# Python regex match expression {m,n} not working as expected

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract percentage value from text string say = "Rate of increase 12.5% per annum" where the percentage could be any decimal less than 100. When I try

```py
re.sub(r'.*([0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]).*',r'\1', text)
```

It returns 2.5. This, I think, should have been the result if it was `{1,2}?`. Also `{1,2}+` returns a *"..multiple match.."* error.
Although I have used some alternative solution, I am curious to understand what I am getting wrong.

Comment: `.*` is greedy; it takes everything it can and only gives back when needed. That being said, it matches `Rate of increase 1` while `[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]` matches `2.5`. If your goal is to extract the match, then there's no need to use `re.sub()`. Just match it using `re.search(r'\d{1,2}\.\d')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by InSync, the issue with your pattern is that the .* at the beginning and end of the pattern is greedy, which means it matches as many characters as possible.

In your example text string, "Rate of increase 12.5% per annum," the .* at the beginning of the pattern matches the entire string up to the last digit before the decimal point (which is 1 in this case). Then, the capturing group ([0-9]{1,2}.[0-9]) matches the remaining digits (2.5) because it satisfies the pattern requirement of having one or two digits before the decimal point and at least one digit after the decimal point. Finally, the .* at the end of the pattern matches the rest of the string (" per annum").

To correct this, you can make the pattern non-greedy by adding a ? after the .* :

```
re.sub(r'.*?([0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]).*', r'\1', text)
```

This modification makes the .*? match as few characters as possible, ensuring that the capturing group ([0-9]{1,2}.[0-9]) captures only the desired decimal number.

With this change, the corrected pattern will extract the expected result, which is 12.5

---

NOTE : if the percentage value could be any decimal less than 100, you might consider modifying the regular expression pattern to allow for numbers greater than 9 before the decimal point. You can use {1,2} to match one or two digits, or you can use {1,2} followed by (?<!\d) to match one or two digits only if they are not preceded by another digit. In this case you have to do like this :

```
result = re.sub(r'.*?(?<!\d)([0-9]+\.[0-9]).*', r'\1', text)
```

This modified pattern ensures that the decimal number is not part of a larger number by using a negative lookbehind assertion (?<!\d) to check that there is no digit immediately preceding the matched decimal number.

Hope it will help you !

Comment: `(?<!\d)` is redundant since you are using lazy quantifier before it.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to extract the match then you can try this below code line:

```
re.sub(r'.*([0-9][0-9].[0-9]).*',r'\1', text)
```

Comment: This is not the same as what OP asked to match. Your regex will fail to match `2.5%`

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

```
match = re.search(r'\b[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]', text)
# match is None if not found
# otherwise the result is in match[0]
```

where `\b` is documented as: *"Matches the empty string, but only at the beginning or end of a word."*